# Session variables for classic ASP running on IIS7

Tags: session, variables, iis-7, asp-classic

Seems that lot of people already know that issue but I can not find solution.

We transferred our web app from IIS6 to IIS7. For authentication purposes and some other functions we using session variables.
While on IIS6 we did not had any problem but now all users losing their time and patience because app variables are being lost somewhere between pages being submitted and as a result users get kicked out of the app.

- Server is 2008 R2 with 64 bit OS.
- Default installation by Dell so it should be running on 64 bit mode.
- We do not have any third party elements or modules. All developed in-house.
- Database obviously MS SQL 2008 as well, on the same server (I know it is bad but we limited in resources and money).

So does anyone know what is going on and how to fix this?

Comment: The issue is your App Pool and what recycling schedule it's set to. Remember also by default there are other recycling settings that determine when an App Pool recycles (like CPU, workers, memory) in IIS 7+ the schedules are particularly aggressive if not configured properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolution of that problem is simple: do not use any other port except 80.
As soon as I moved site to separate IP with port 80 (use of header on the same IP was not tested) -- all problem gone....

Comment: @AllBlond This is accepted? The issue is your App Pool and what recycling schedule it's set to. Remember also by default there are other recycling settings that determine when an App Pool recycles (like CPU, workers, memory) in IIS 7+ the schedules are particularly aggressive if not configured properly.

Comment: @Lankymart, that what was worked for me as well. Besides, no one else said anything which would of making sense or help me resolve the issue at the time. And that was production server with lot of unique visitors per minute...

Comment: @AllBlond What is more likely is this just masked your issue and the act of changing your port assignment probably recycled your site. A solution that forces you switch the port or ip address you are binding isn't a solution and will not help people who come here looking for one.

Answer (score 0):

Have you deployed your application as a new website or a virtual directory on the IIS ?
Remember that for the methods in the global.asa to be executed by the server you need to deploy your application as a new website not just a virtual directory under an existing web site.

Comment: That is new web app(site) under IIS7

Comment: it uses individual app pool with 32 bit enabled settings.

Comment: One more detail: it uses port 8080

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to add logging code to trace when exactly a session variable is lost; after a post back to the server, redirection, etc... to try to narrow down the causes.
good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Look [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/distributedservices/archive/2010/04/28/iis-intrinsic-properties-are-disabled-by-default-on-windows-2008-and-windows-2008-r2.aspx) for a solution...

the intrinsic checkbox fixed my problem